# Como acceder a los checkboxs por el nombre o cualquier otra forma con vba

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy creando checkbox de forma dinámica

```
cant = Hoja5.Range("V18")
L = 1376.25
T = 42
W = 14.5
H = 12.5
For I = 1 To cant
    Hoja5.OLEObjects.Add "Forms.CheckBox.1", Left:=L, Top:=T, Width:=W, Height:=H
    T = T + 15
Next I
```

Y quisiera acceder a ellos para saber su estado. El checkbox1 ya lo tengo creado y es fijo para otro proceso, por lo que los generados son a partir del checkbox2... El código se ejecuta sobre la misma hoja5. ¿Como puedo comprobar su valor sin incluir al checkbox1?
Gracias.-

Answer (score 3):

Despues de estar mirando y probando código, me decidi a exponerlo aqui, y como es mi "norma" doy con la solución, despues de pulsar el "enter".

```
 For J = 2 To Me.Range("V18") + 1
     If Me.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & J).Object.Value Then
         C = C + 1
     End If
 Next J
```